# Qt application - open one process only

Tags: qt, process

I have Qt GUI application which I want that the user will open one only. I want that if the user will click first time on th exe - it will open the application and when he will click it again it will open the first one.

i don't want to do it with QtSingleApplication.
I want to know exacly how to open the GUI on the second time.

Help me please!

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087235/how-to-force-my-application-to-open-one-exe-only-qt-linux

Comment: what I wantis to open the GUI if the process is already running,

Comment: You can do that using QtSingleApplication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you don't want to, `QtSingleApplication` is what works. If you want to learn how it is implemented, you can always [read the source code](http://qt.nokia.com/products/appdev/add-on-products/catalog/4/Utilities/qtsingleapplication/).

Comment: @gln: Maybe your question could then be rephrased as how to make it work. For example, what you've attempted and how it fails.

Comment: I fails to include the headers. I put the QtSingleApplication and QtLocalPeer h and cpp in my project but it does :undefined reference to QLocalServer...

Comment: @gln: See the Install.txt file in the QtSingleApplication archive for detailed instructions. In this case, you need to add `QT += network` to your project file.